# How can I make old style classes work in typescript?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-5

While converting a large number of files to typescript, I have many classes declared this way.

```
function FooClass() {
    this.bar = 1; // error TS2683: 'this' implicitly has type 'any'
                  // because it does not have a type annotation.
}

FooClass.prototype.myMethod = function() {
    // ...
}
```

How can I make this work with strict type checking turned on, while avoiding rewriting it all using class syntax?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way to get the above code to work is to add a [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters) to the function, like so:

```
function FooClass(this: {bar: number}) {
    this.bar = 1; // okay
}
```

Unfortunately, you will soon find that the compiler doesn't know what to make of `FooClass` when you treat it like a constructor:

```
const oops = new FooClass(); // error, oops is implicitly any
oops.bar // okay but compiler has no idea
oops.myMethod() // okay but also no idea
oops.foo // also okay, but you probably don't want it to be
oops.yourMethod() // ditto
```

This is apparently [by design](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2310).  The best way to annotate this, in my opinion, is to define the types `FooClass` and `FooConstructor` in advance:

```
interface FooClass {
  bar: number;
  myMethod(): void;
}

interface FooConstructor {
  new(): FooClass,
  prototype: FooClass
}
```

Note that when you use the `class FooClass {}` way of creating constructors, TypeScript automatically generates both a *value* `FooClass` which is the constructor itself, and a *type* `FooClass` which is the type of the instances created by the constructor.  This is often confusing to developers, so take care.  We are doing that here manually: the above `interface FooClass` is the *type*, not the *value*, which we are about to create.

After you define those types, assert that the `FooClass` function is of type `FooConstructor` when you create it (the assertion needs to pass though `Function` or `any` and is not safe, so be careful).

```
const FooClass = function FooClass(this: FooClass) {
  this.bar = 1;
} as Function as FooConstructor;

FooClass.prototype.myMethod = function () {
  // ...
}
```

And test it out:

```
const okay = new FooClass();
okay.bar // number
okay.myMethod() // known
okay.foo // error, yay
okay.yourMethod() // error, yay
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: I'd rename Foo interface to FooClass in order to make types work similarly to ES6 classes, `let foo: FooClass`.

Comment: I'm going back and forth on that.  It makes me want to go into a lengthy aside about how there's a *type* named `FooClass` and a *value* named `FooClass` and they are not the same etc etc.

Comment: `interface FooClass` could be percieved as type merge (although it isn't). I guess the decisive factor here is that `const FooClass` doesn't produce type of same name, so there's no naming collision. `let foo: FooClass` would result in type error otherwise.

Comment: Fine, lengthy aside added.

Comment: This answer is great and very thorough. It seems there is no way to avoid declaring the interface, which is only slightly less work than reformatting them using class syntax. So that it what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to convert them, I'd suggest to keep them as JavaScript files and just write declaration files for them. Then TypeScript would recognise them implicitly, without rewriting the code.

You could add to your project a `types.d.ts` file and:

```
declare class FooClass {
    public bar: number;
    public myMethod: () => void;
    ...
}
```

With such a file in your project, TypeScript will allow you to do `const myClass = new FooClass();`.

Of course, you still have to add your JavaScript code (or you'll run into runtime errors), importing it the way that suits you. If you were using global files, by loading them in your page, or in whichever environment you're working on. If your old code was in modules, you import those modules when you need to use them.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that TypeScript v3.6.2 seems to behave differently when in the context of .js files. The following ECMAScript 5 style class seems fortunately to be type inferred and the two expected type offenses detected:

```
/**
 * @class Person
 * @param {string} name
 */
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name
}

var person = new Person("John")
person.foo // TS2339: Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'Person'.
person.name

new Person(42) // Argument of type '42' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

This could be confirmed with:

```
$ tsc --checkJs --allowJs --noImplicitAny --strictNullChecks test.js
```

Reverting back to a .js file therefore could be one way to continue with the original inheritance style.

For subclasses, however, this method seems to break. I've posted the details to https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18171.